# Distorted CVImageBuffer to UIImage

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, cgimage, ciimage

I have the following function that converts `CVImageBugger` to `UIImage`. The image that comes out is always a little bit distorted. I display the return value of this function in a `UIImageView`, which is set to 'aspect fill'. What gives?...

```
private func convert(buffer: CVImageBuffer) -> UIImage? {
    let cmage: CIImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: buffer)
    let context: CIContext = CIContext(options: nil)
    if let cgImage: CGImage = context.createCGImage(cmage, from: cmage.extent) {
        return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `CVImageBuffer` doesn't contain the orientation information, maybe that's why the final UIImage is distorted.

The default orientation of `CVImageBuffer` is always Landscape(like the iPhone's Home button is at right side), no matter if you capture a video with portrait way or not.

So we need to add good orientation information to the image:

```
extension CIImage {
    func orientationCorrectedImage() -> UIImage? {
        var imageOrientation = UIImageOrientation.up
        switch UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation {
        case UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait:
            imageOrientation = UIImageOrientation.right
        case UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft:
            imageOrientation = UIImageOrientation.down
        case UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeRight:
            imageOrientation = UIImageOrientation.up
        case UIInterfaceOrientation.portraitUpsideDown:
            imageOrientation = UIImageOrientation.left
        default:
            break;
        }

        var w = self.extent.size.width
        var h = self.extent.size.height

        if imageOrientation == .left || imageOrientation == .right || imageOrientation == .leftMirrored || imageOrientation == .rightMirrored {
            swap(&w, &h)
        }

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: w, height: h));
        UIImage.init(ciImage: self, scale: 1.0, orientation: imageOrientation).draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: w, height: h))
        let uiImage:UIImage? = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        return uiImage
    }
}
```

Then use it with your code:

```
private func convert(buffer: CVImageBuffer) -> UIImage? {
    let ciImage: CIImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: buffer)
    return ciImage.orientationCorrectedImage()
}
```

Comment: Thanks Yun.. but unfortunately it's still very elongated.. Also my image is not oriented incorrectly. It's just elongated..

Comment: @7ball, Could you provide the screenshot?